# Ajax post request (HTML to Express app) not working

Tags: javascript, jquery, node.js, ajax, express

I am building a node express app for storing recipes. Via a 'new recipe' html form, users can add as many ingredients as they need, which are dynamically displayed via jquery and stored in an 'ingredients' array. Because I can't send this array via HTTP, I'm trying to send a new recipe object via an AJAX post request. I have limited experience with AJAX, and I cannot understand why the post request is not working at all. Here's my front end jquery:

```
script type="text/javascript">
    //$(document).ready(() => alert("Jquery works!"));
    $(document).ready(() => {
        $("#addIngBtn").click(() => {
            let ingredient = $("#ingredient").val();
            let quantity = $("#quantity").val();
            $("#ingredient").val(""); //reset ingredient input
            $("#quantity").val("");
            $("ul").append(
                "<li>" + ingredient + " - " + quantity + "</li>"
            );
        });
    })

    $("#newRecipeForm").submit(() => {
        event.preventDefault();
        var ingredients = [];
        $("#ingredientListUL li").each((index, element) =>
            ingredients.push($(element).text())
        )
        var recipe = {
            name: $("#name").val(),
            image: $("#image").val(),
            oneLiner: $("#oneLiner").val(),
            method: $("#method").val(),
            ingredients: ingredients
        }
        $.ajax({
            url: "/recipes",
            type: "POST",
            dataType: "json",
            data: recipe,
            contentType: "application/json",
            complete: function () {
                console.log("process complete");
            },
            success: function (data) {
                console.log(data);
                console.log("process success");
            },
            error: function () {
                console.log(err);
            }
        })

    })
```

And my backend:

```
// note, this is in router file where default route "/" is equivalent to "/recipes"
router.post("/", (req, res) => {
    console.log(req.body.recipe);

})
```

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: " I cannot understand why the post request is not working at all" — What does this mean? Does the Network tab of the browser's developer tools not show the request? Does the `console.log(req.body.recipe)` log something unexpected? Or throw an exception?

Comment: "And my backend" — You should provide a [mcve]. It's hard to tell if the problem is caused by something you have in your server code that you omitted from the question or something that would expected to be in your server code but that you've omitted.

Comment: Try replacing `data: recipe,` with `data: JSON.stringify(recipe),`

Comment: Do you have this line in your backend? ```app.use(express.json());```

Comment: Not an expert here, but the data your are sending doesn't contain the recipe key. In your backend try

    router.post("/", (req, res) => {
        console.log(req.body.name);
    })

Comment: Sorry @Quentin, request is not showing in network tools so no post request is being sent so console.log() shows nothing.

Comment: To close queue people: a Bootstrap include messed up the `$.ajax` call and the browser never sent out the xhr in the first place.

Answer (score 0):

Not an expert here, but the data your are sending doesn't contain the recipe key. In your backend (haha) try

```
router.post("/", (req, res) => { 
    console.log(req.body.name); 
})
```