# Sending POST data via AJAX to NodeJS server

Tags: javascript, node.js, ajax, express

I have made basic web apps whereby data is sent via HTTP parameters. However, I am trying to send data from client-side that contains an array (a list of ingredients for a recipe) and eventually, hopefully user uploaded image (but not worried about that for now). For this I know I need to use AJAX. I have spent hours trying to get it to work but for some reason, no POST request is being sent. The user inputs are fairly basic but here's a snippet:

```
 <label for="method"> Method </label>
    <textarea id="method" name="method">method here</textarea>
    </br>
    <p> add ingredients </p>
    <input name="ingredient" id="ingredient" placeholder="add ingredient">
    <input name="quantity" id="quantity" placeholder="#"><button id="addIngBtn" type="button">Add</button><br>
    <button type="submit">submit</button>
    <p> Ingredients:</p>
    <ul id="ingredientListUL">
```

I use JQUERY to allow users to append as many ingredients as they want to the list:

```
  $(document).ready(() => {
        $("#addIngBtn").click(() => {
            let ingredient = $("#ingredient").val();
            let quantity = $("#quantity").val();
            $("#ingredient").val(""); //reset ingredient input
            $("#quantity").val("");
            $("ul").append(
                "<li>" + ingredient + " - " + quantity + "</li>"
            );
        });
    })
```

Ingredients are built into an array and then added to a new recipe object which is the data I want to send to my server:

```
var ingredients = [];
          $("#ingredientListUL li").each((index, element) =>
              ingredients.push($(element).text())
          )
          var recipe = {
              name: $("#name").val(),
              image: $("#image").val(),
              oneLiner: $("#oneLiner").val(),
              method: $("#method").val(),
              ingredients: ingredients
          }
```

So far so good. I presume I am doing something wrong with these next parts. Here's the AJAX post request:

```
$.ajax({
            url: "http://localhost:5000/recipes",
            type: "POST",
            dataType: "json",
            data: recipe,
            contentType: "application/json",
            complete: function () {
                console.log("process complete");
            },
            success: function (data) {
                console.log(data);
                console.log("process success");
            },
            error: function () {
                console.log(err);
            }
        })
```

And here's my server info:

```
// express setup
const express = require("express");
const app = express();
const port = 5000;

// set templating engine to EJS
app.set('view engine', 'ejs');

// import route files
const recipeRoutes = require("./routes/recipes")
app.use("/recipes", recipeRoutes);

// body parser
const bodyParser = require("body-parser");
app.use(bodyParser.urlencoded({ extended: true }));
app.use(bodyParser.json())

//--
// BASIC ROUTES
//--

app.get("/", (req, res) => res.render("landing"));


// Port
app.listen(port, () => console.log(`Server starting on port ${port}!`));
```

All routes, are stored in a recipe routes file, which contains the post route for this request:

```
// default "/" route is really "/recipes" as defined in main server file.
router.post("/", (req, res) => {

    console.log(req.body.recipe);

})
```

The problem is that nothing appears to be sent to, or received by my server according to network tab. Even when I try to send something like:

```
        $.post("http://localhost:5000/recipes", { test: "test" })
```

What am I doing wrong? Thanks.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Ajax post request (HTML to Express app) not working](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60253392/ajax-post-request-html-to-express-app-not-working)

Comment: Your server works fine when hit via Postman or any other rest client? Or even CURL?

Comment: @chrisG JSON.stringify(recipe) didn't seem to make a difference. Even a simple {test:"test"} is not being sent.

Comment: It made a difference for me when I tested your code; without it jQuery is turning the parameters into a query string, but you want to send an array among other data, and use JSON instead. In my browser's network tab I could see the xhr and its parameters just fine.

Comment: @ChrisG thanks, that was a problem for sure, but there must be something else preventing my post request from being received by the server. Just can't figure out what. Probably something embarrassingly silly.

Comment: Can you add a GET route to your recipes controller and go to `http://localhost:5000/recipes` in the browser?

Comment: Also, using `$.post()` *must* result in the browser sending an XHR (or showing an error message of some kind). Make sure your console displays XHR and double-check that one is being sent and what the reply is.

Comment: I found this error :  Uncaught TypeError: $.ajax is not a function. But I have checked to ensure jquery is connect and that it is not a slim version (ie version that doesn't include ajax)

Comment: How are you including jQuery? Are you including any other library that might overwrite `$`? Have you tried `jQuery.ajax` / `jQuery.post` instead?

Comment: @ChrisG Oh my goodness it was my Bootstrap CDN that was messing everything up. I included the right Jquery library but bootstrap was overwriting it. I knew it was going to be something dumb. Can't believe I wasted hours on this lol. Thanks for your help.

Comment: You're welcome :) And don't forget to delete the two questions if possible

Answer (score 0):

The contentType property does not work that way. It indicates if it is URL encoded, as a multipart message, etc. Try removing it.

According to: https://api.jquery.com/jquery.ajax/ :

> "If you explicitly pass in a content-type to $.ajax(), then it is
>   always sent to the server (even if no data is sent)"

Comment: Thank you, I have removed this but it is still not working. Even the test data is not being sent/received still: $.post("http://localhost:5000/recipes", { test: "test" })
    })